# Stretching TextBlock inside button

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm building a vertical button bar. There is an image and a TextBlock on each button. All buttons will scale together in width and height depending on font size and number of characters in the TextBlock. It is desired that the TextBlock with the fewest number of characters is stretched to take up the remaining space and to push the image as far left as possible. The problem seems to be not being able to stretch the TextBlock (the TextBlock with fewer characters) to fill the remaining space on the button bar. How can I do this?

```
    <ScrollViewer>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Background>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlLightColorKey}}"/>
        </Grid.Background>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button 
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="1" 
            Margin="2"
            Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=Tb}"
            Click="Button1_Click">
            <!---->
            <DockPanel>
                <Image 
                    Source="/images/block_arrow_left.png"
                    Grid.Row="0" 
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=Tb}" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                </Image>
                <TextBlock 
                    x:Name="Tb"
                    Padding="5"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Grid.Row="0" 
                    Grid.Column="1" 
                    FontSize="14"
                    Text="button1">
                </TextBlock>
            </DockPanel>
        </Button>
        <Button 
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="1" 
            Margin="2"
            Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=Tb}"
            Click="Button2_Click">
            <DockPanel>
                <Image 
                    Source="images/block_arrow_left.png"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Grid.Row="1" 
                    Grid.Column="0" 
                    Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=Tb}" >
                </Image>
                <TextBlock 
                    Padding="5"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Grid.Row="1" 
                    Grid.Column="0" 
                    FontSize="14"
                    Text="button22222222222222">
                </TextBlock>
            </DockPanel>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your button content isn't taking up the entire interior space of the buttons. If you set a `Background` brush on the DockPanels, that will be apparent.

To make the content stretch to its parent, set `HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"` on the buttons:

```
<Button 
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
    Margin="2"
    Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=Tb}"
    Click="Button1_Click">
    <!-- button content -->
```

Comment: Super. That does it. Thanks Ed.